# Read DLL content programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, decompiler

I am working on a small c# console application that will check my .net DLL and look for environment specific information from compiled dll.

Basically, I want to check c# Web published project and display any file contain production specific information developer forgot to update...

Issue: I am running into is when a developer switch between environment from Dev to test and test to prod. They forget to switch their environment value either in C# or web.config file.

Is there a way I can open individual DLL and extract the DLL content as a **string** using C# code and a free decompiler?

Comment: Header Typo:  grammatically should be Programmatically.

Comment: Then click `edit` and fix it.

Comment: Sounds like your dev ops process is all backwards. Devs shouldn't have to worry about swapping environment variables. Your releases should go through an automated system that performs the necessary configuration.

Comment: What do you think you would be doing with that text? Even if you parse and analyze it all, how do you think you would ever know that `if(env != 17)` means test code is executed? Some things can only be solved by having a real talk with the sloppy developers (which in turn should result in CI procedures that take that whole crap off the devs hands anyway).

Comment: If your code had some hard coded values which can alter the behavior of the application between dev and prod environment then you need to move them to config file. And you need to have proper build mechanism to inject the environment specific config values in config files while creating build package for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

#if DEBUG
[assembly:AssemblyConfiguration("debug")]
#else
[assembly:AssemblyConfiguration("release")]
#endif

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            // this should be the filename of your DLL
            var filename = typeof(Program).Assembly.Location;

            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(filename);
            var data = assembly.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(AssemblyConfigurationAttribute));
            if (data != null)
            {
                // this will be the argument to AssemblyConfigurationAttribute
                var arg = data.ConstructorArguments.First().Value.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(arg);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```